# Motivate dynamic time warping using ccf or heatmap?

Tags: r, cross-correlation, dtw, saf

I have 20 time series each with different length and different time stamps (for example TS1 start 00:15 and ends 23:50 and TS2 start 00:30 and ends 23:00). I want to use dtw but i dont know how to motivate it.

I am thinking about using two time series and get ccf for each lag and plot the heatmap. But does ccf even interpretable when i have time series with different length? The hypothesis is that time series with similar surface structure as such as a high proportion of roads, are similar to each other.

My data looks something like this:

```
Area   Time    Day   Value    surface
1      00:30   1      0.2         50% roads
...
1      23:30   1      2.6        50% roads
......
2      00:15   1      2.7         48% roads
...
```

i did not find anything about the motivation of dtw using ccf of time series with different length